# WPF TextBox shows 1 instead of 0 which it is supposed to

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have got this problem. A WPF TextBox shows 1 instead of 0, when 0 is observed in debugging mode for TextBox.text. Here is the xmal code for the TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="powerText" ToolTip="Enter the power value to go to" Width="100"
VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Here is the C# code for the button-click that fires the 0 setting event for the TextBox:

```
private void Set_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (powerText.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            ((LiveImageViewModel)this.DataContext).PowerPosition = 
Convert.ToInt32(powerText.Text);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            string str = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The `powerText.Text` was observed 0, but the UI shows 1! I am super confused why this is happening, and how I should correct it? Anyone thoughts are appreciated?Thanks a lot.

Comment: you mean Convert.ToInt32 is converting 0 to 1?

Comment: Need more code ie what is `.PowerPosition` and why not use `Text="{Binding yourValue}"` and use a ViewModel instead of code-behind?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` returns 0 if the value passed in is `null`. Are you sure you're passing in `"1"`?

Comment: I copied your example into a blank solution and replaced the `(LiveImageViewModel)` line with `var x = Convert.ToInt32(powerText.Text);` and x resulted in whatever I typed in the textbox (e.g. 123) so, again would need more code to determine why that conversion is not **what you expect**

Comment: Clearly, `TextBox.Text` values do *not* change themselves. This means that *your* code is changing it somewhere and it doesn't look like its happening in this code that you have shown.

Comment: **Important:** Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. **Translation to everyday language:** Please remove this horrible code behind HACK from your application immediately and forget winforms forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works for me if I change the view model cast part (as you didnt supply that code):

x results in whatever I have typed into text box, e.g. 123

```
            try
            {
                var x = Convert.ToInt32(powerText.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                string str = ex.Message;
            }
```

So we would need to see more info on the `((LiveImageViewModel)this.DataContext).PowerPosition` objects to see why you are not seeing what you *expect*